# Newbie SQL error; missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Newbie to sql here

I am attempting return sa_id from the query below but I am getting a 'missing expression' error.

```
select s.sa_id
    from cisadm.ci_sa s
    where s.sa_status_flg = '20'
    and s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
    and s.sa_id in {
      select *
      from cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
      where pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI'}
    ;
```

The sa_id exists in both tables; ci_sa and ci_intv_pf.

I need the sa_id to have a intv_pf_typ_cd of 'SMPCHGRI' in the ci_intv_pf table.
And I need the matching sa_id to have an sa_type_cd of 'LEURIBIL' from the ci_sa table.

Have tried ending the query with group by and having but not having any luck.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: `s.sa_id in ( select sa_id.. )`

Comment: Thanks @Prdp It was a bracket issue, should have been using parentheses!

Comment: Not just bracket. You cannot select more than one column when you are using `IN`. Select `sa_id` alone in sub query

Comment: @LiamC - You have three possible answers below. If any of them answer your question you can mark that answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a standard sub-query as you are attempting in your question;

```
SELECT s.sa_id
FROM   cisadm.ci_sa s
WHERE  s.sa_status_flg = '20'
AND    s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
AND    s.sa_id IN (SELECT pf.sa_id
                   FROM   cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
                   WHERE  pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI')
```

A correlated sub-query is also possible using EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.sa_id
FROM   cisadm.ci_sa s
WHERE  s.sa_status_flg = '20'
AND    s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
AND    s.sa_id EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
                       WHERE  pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI'
                       AND    pf.sa_id = s.sa_id)
```

And then there's using WITH to refactor the sub-query which can make complex queries a bit easier to read;

```
WITH sub_query AS
(SELECT 1
 FROM   cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
 WHERE  pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI')
SELECT  s.sa_id
FROM   cisadm.ci_sa s
       INNER JOIN 
       sub_query pf ON pf.sa_id = s.sa_id
WHERE  s.sa_status_flg = '20'
AND    s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
```

There will likely be some differences in efficiency for all these based largely on the relative sizes of the tables but Oracle does a pretty good job of picking the most efficient way nowadays.

Caveat: I haven't actually set up tables and data to test these

Answer (score 1):

Just return the sa_id in the inner SQL:

```
select s.sa_id
    from cisadm.ci_sa s
    where s.sa_status_flg = '20'
    and s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
    and s.sa_id in (
      select pf.sa_id 
      from cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
      where pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI')
    ;
```

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks. I need to use parentheses instead of brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Endorsing Prdp, however, please consider following code that is little bit faster as it reads count instead of values -

```
select s.sa_id
from cisadm.ci_sa s
where s.sa_status_flg = '20'
and s.sa_type_cd = 'LEURIBIL'
and exist (
                    select  1
                    from    cisadm.ci_intv_pf pf
                    where   pf.intv_pf_typ_cd = 'SMPCHGRI'
                    and s.sa_id = pf.sa_id
        );
```

Comment: It CAN be faster but it depends on the relative cardinality between the two tables. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074 explains quite well - as always

Comment: BriteSponge, agreed.